# Whenever I try to open a url in the internet browser from my application, the browser crashes and says something about an SD card. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, browser, android-studio, sd-card

The browser crashes too fast to read the error but I can read that it says something about the SD card. I am using a real android device which has an SD card installed.

Here is the code of the button that is pressed to upen the link:

```
private void goToUrl (String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}

public void startNewActivityDresscode (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.adams12.org/files/dms/5060-042613.pdf"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Please provide your logcat error and full snippet of the code

Comment: I found out the problem. USB mass storage was on.